# unusual value while reading a file

Tags: read.table

I checked the number of input lines with unix [wc -l], it is 578537. However, when I read this file in R, I get 658926. I checked the R output and there is output like 'XN:i:0' at some lines. So I am wondering what is this and how did I get it in R? Is it something related to regular expressions? Would like to dig on this topic a bit more to understand how this values appear after read.table.

```
f=read.table("file.sam", sep="\t", skip=3, quote ="", fill=T, comment.char = "")[,c(1,10,11)]    
# I need values of 1st, 10th and 11th column, and some lines have less values than others; skip 3 is for skipping SAM header
```

## dummy output

```
M00547:13:00:20456 TGTTTCTGTA //99009
M00547:13:00:25175 AGACTAATTA hegffghg
XN:i:0
M00547:13:00:10803 TTATTATGTT 09;;00..
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read a SAM (Sequence Alignment Map) file as if it were a single table.   That's not going to work, a SAM is structured chunked data.   You should use a package like 'rsamtools' to read your BAM/SAM.

Comment: you are right, I also found at bowtie2 documnetation following, whic proves that my initial file has this flag, "XN:i:<N>
The number of ambiguous bases in the reference covering this alignment. Only present if SAM record is for an aligned read"